# norm of inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, random-matrices

Given that $D\gg 1$ (integer) and $\delta\ll 1$ (small positive real). Suppose $v$ is a fixed unit vector, and $u\sim \mbox{Unif}(\sqrt D\mathbb S^{D-1})$. Can we meaningfully bound the norm of $(uv^T+\delta I)^{-1}$ with very high probability, as in $||(uv^T+\delta I)^{-1}||={\tilde O}(\delta^{-1})$, where the hidden constant is allowed to depend on $D$ but only logarithmically? Weyl's perturbation theorem says $||(uv^T+\delta I)^{-1}||\geq \delta^{-1}$; is there maybe an almost matching upper bound, or any hope of having one?

Comment: Which norm is $\|\cdot\|$? The spectral norm?

Comment: Yes. I meant the spectral norm.

Answer (score 1):

A possibly helpful perspective: by the Sherman Morrison formula, we see that $(uv^T + \delta I)$ is invertible if and only if $u^Tv \neq -\delta$, and in this case we have
$$
(uv^T + \delta I)^{-1} = \delta^{-1} I - \frac{uv^T}{\delta^2 + \delta u^Tv}.
$$
If we take $\|\cdot\|$ to be the spectral norm, then the triangle inequality yields
$$
\|(uv^T + \delta I)^{-1}\| \leq \delta^{-1} + \frac{\sqrt{D}}{|\delta^2 + \delta u^Tv|}.
$$
However, as $u^Tv \to -\delta$, the norm of the inverse becomes arbitrarily high.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. A question: did you mean to write $(uv^T+\delta I)^{-1}=\delta^{-1}I-\frac{uv^T}{\delta^2+\delta u^Tv}$, and $||(uv^T+\delta I)^{-1}||\leq \delta^{-1}+\frac{|v^Tu|}{|\delta^2+\delta u^Tv|}$? In that case, it looks like we get at least a quadratic dependence on $\delta^{-1}$.

Comment: @orthoped You're right, I missed a factor of $\delta$ there. I'm not sure what exactly you mean by a "quadratic dependence on $\delta^{-1}$" here.

Comment: there is a slight error in the norm inequality, as $||uv^T||\leq |u^Tv|$ is not true. For example, $u\bot v$ does not necessarily imply $uv^T$ is zero matrix --- which must be the case if $||uv^T||\leq |u^Tv|$ is true.

Comment: Not sure how I made that mistake. See my latest edit